# Performance counter collection

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Is there any way to get a collection of Performance counters ?

What I mean is, instead of creating several performance counters , such as

```
PerformanceCounter actions = new PerformanceCounter("CategoryName", "CounterName1","instance");
PerformanceCounter tests = new PerformanceCounter("CategoryName", "CounterName2", "instance");
```

I would like to get a collection (for CategoryName) where each item will be a CounterName item.

So there is no need in separate counters creations.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your description I believe you want to create custom counters. You can create the counters at once but you must create their instance one by one.

Use the [CounterCreationDataCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countercreationdatacollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [CounterCreationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countercreationdata.aspx) classes. First, create the counters data, add them to the new counter category and then create their instances:

```
//Create the counters data. You could also use a loop here if your counters will have exactly these names.
CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
counters.Add(new CounterCreationData("CounterName1", "Description of Counter1", PerformanceCounterType.AverageCount64));
counters.Add(new CounterCreationData("CounterName2", "Description of Counter2", PerformanceCounterType.AverageCount64));

//Create the category with the prwviously defined counters.
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("CategoryName", "CategoryDescription", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, counters);

//Create the Instances
CategoryName actions = new PerformanceCounter("CategoryName", "CounterName1", "Instance1", false));
CategoryName tests = new PerformanceCounter("CategoryName", "CounterName2", "Instance1", false));
```

My suggestion is not to use general names as counters names. After you create the counters you possibly want to collect their data (perhaps through performance monitor), so instead of `CounteName1` use as name what the counter represents (e.g. actions, tests...).

**EDIT**

To get all counters of a specific category at once create an instance of the counter category and use the [GetCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew6c05xw.aspx) method:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("CategoryName");
PerformanceCounter[] counters = category.GetCounters("instance");

foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in counters)
{
    //do something with the counter
}
```

Comment: Actually not,
I don't want to create a custom counters, but I want to use application built in counters.
So instead of creating each Performance Counter as a stand a lone, I would like to get all the data (counters) of some Category name at once... is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: @user301639 please check my edited answer. I hope this this is what you want.

Comment: great, this is the way I looked for. 
Thanks